# Using Output from one Function and calling it into another

Tags: functions, variables

I'm trying to get my head around a fairly simple concept in PHP but I'm pretty green.

I have a function..

```
function pa_insertPage($atts, $content = null) {
    // Default output if no pageid given
    $output = NULL;
    // extract atts and assign to array
    extract(shortcode_atts(array("page" => '2404' // Value for Course Descriptions page
    ), $atts));
    // if a page id is specified, then run query
    if (!empty($page)) {
        $pageContent = new WP_query();
        $pageContent->query(array('page_id' => $page));
        while ($pageContent->have_posts()) : $pageContent->the_post();
            // assign the content to $output
            $output = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        endwhile;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

And I'd like to use the returned `$output` from this function in another function called `naada_assess()`

In my `naada_assess` function I've called `$recClasses =  pa_insertPage($output);` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a WordPress question... that said

```
$recClasses = pa_insertPage($output);
```

is incorrect. here you should be passing to insertPage whatever the arguments are. Then insertPage will return $output, making $recClasses the same value as $output.

```
    $recClasses = pa_insertPage('your attributes');
// $recClasses now equals $output;
```

Comment: Might be a WordPress question... looks like a shortcode callback to me.

Comment: Thanks Vancoder!  Yes I understood it to be a PHP question, but I haven't yet found a good PHP help forum.  Do you know of any? Your response took care of my issue easily and highlighted my poor ability to see and understand the problem.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes it is a WP shortcode, but I decided not to use it as such, but have it's output be placed into another function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a shortcode like this:

```
 add_shortcode('myshortcode','pa_insertPage');
```

then you could try this inside your `naada_assess()` function:

```
$recClasses = do_shortcode('[myshortcode page="123"]');
```

as a way to retrieve the `$output`.

Comment: thanks!  This looks to easily accomplish the same thing.  Everytime I struggle and ask for help, I see that there isn't only 1 way to solve the problem.